# Scolling ImageView From Server Using Picasso

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I have a picture that is vertically expandable. The picture is retrieved from the server (link) and shown by using picasso.

I have tried many references but did not successfully. This is my code :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FCE6C0"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/langkah_resep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the picasso :

```
Picasso
.with(getBaseContext())
.load(langkah_resep)
.fit()
.into(imgResep);
```

When I removed the ScrollView, the image is shown, but when I put the ScrollView nothing is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling an image in a ScrollView isn't something that a lot of users might be familiar with. Is there a particular reason for wanting to put the image in a ScrollView?

Another possible solution would be to remove the ScrollView and use something like PhotoView to allow pinch & zoom of the image instead.

See: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

It works fine with Picasso as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add a min **height** & **width** for the ImageView and it should do the trick.

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/langkah_resep"
            android:minHeight="64dp"
            android:minWidth="64dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```